# Testing symmetrical high-speed Internet connections

Tags: internet-connection, speed, network-monitoring

Is there a tool that I can use on a sever that will allow me to measure throughput for symmetrical circuits on a closed controled network to a select group of clients? If not how do I go about building one. I'm not a programmer but I'm willing to do what it takes to learn. I'm looking for something simple and graphical to show clients Green is "good" or Red is "bad".

Answer (score 0):

It wont show Red = Bad, Green = Good, but you can use the [SpeedTest.NET mini](http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php) test on your own server. I used it internally to test wifi links on my own servers. It works quite well. You do need your own web servers though.